# I am getting NumberFormatException while converting String into Intger

Tags: java, android

I have an php api which give me array like this:

﻿11%0%0%801%0%0%812%0%0%640%33%6

Above response is going to be stored in *"String a"*

```
try{
    //... Some code of my application which is not relavant to show
    String a = response.toString();
    String tokens = a.split("%");
    for (String str : tokens)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", str);
    }
    String ds = tokens[0];
    int i_ds = Integer.parseInt(ds);
    Log.e("log_tag", "data is: "+i_ds);
}catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("log_tag","Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

I am getting following in my DDMS:

```
Tag         Text
log_tag     11
log_tag     0
log_tag     0
log_tag     801
log_tag     0
log_tag     0
log_tag     812
log_tag     0
log_tag     0
log_tag     640
log_tag     33
log_tag     6
log_tag     java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:"11"
```

Comment: How does this compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Just copied and pasted your code, although other comments do state the truth that you do need to make this change: String [] tokens = a.split("%");

Looks like php is passing you some fun hidden characters! Theres a hidden character before the number 11, I would sanitize your string by doing the following

```
tokens[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it would not, trim() only removes spaces (" ") not hidden characters, its a series of UTF8 chars leading his string getting passed from the php code. My eclipse tells me so!

Comment: I checked method `trim()`. It removes white characters, so \n,\t also.

Comment: Well, I dont know what to tell you other than I copied and pasted his code, ran it and trim did not work....

Comment: So it seems, that it is different white character. Nevermind, you code is working.

Comment: Thanks @ns47731 , could you please tell me more about these hidden characters?

Comment: Hidden characters are just characters that are not generally visually rendered by most editors. If you take a look at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ you notice lots of character entries with no actual "character". When a program goes to save a file on your hard-drive it isn't going to limit itself just to the characters you can see, its going to use all characters available even ones you cant see with a basic text editor. You were getting some in your code. Many times you can find these by using your arrow keys to go through the string and see if the | doesnt move when you hit left or right.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.split`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns a `String[]`

Replace 
`String tokens = a.split("%");`
with 
`String[] tokens = a.split("%");`